How do you take a loop cycling through multiple columns, looking for last open cell and pasting then Repeating 31 times
I am copy and pasting 31 different cells(all over a worksheet) to another worksheet. I have each cell being copied and pasted to a new sheet. That sheet loops through a specific column to find an empty row, paste. Then to the next and next, however the way I have this set up has error if one last row has one missing cell. Then the next time this runs it will past in this cell and not aligning with the rest of the data in the entire row. This is just 2 blocks of data and not all 31.
Code:
Windows("JOB_COST_FORM.xlsm").Activate
Range("C22").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("MasterList_JOBCOST.xlsm").Activate       'quote
Range("A2").Select
If Range("A2") = "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Else: Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If

Then this would run through 31 more blocks of code like this but with a different Range
My question is this. If one cell is blank, then when the code goes to check that cell of data it won't line up with the rest of the correct row of data.

Side note: in general, you want to avoid using Select in your code

Yes, I need to go learn removing the select, what to use in its place.  Thank you

Also, there is no actual loop in your code (both above and in your answer). If you were to provide some sample data, and the expected outcome, something more efficient could probably be done.

I did remove the loop inside this, I will Edit this question to clear up the question since a loop is not present. Thanks

Here's a quick example of how to implement your code by separating the common part into a separate sub:
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim sourceWB As Workbook
    Dim sourceWS As Worksheet
    'Set sourceWB = Workbooks("JOB_COST_FORM.xlsm")
    Set sourceWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set sourceWS = sourceWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim destWB As Workbook
    Dim destWS As Worksheet
    'Set destWB = Workbooks("MasterList_JOBCOST.xlsm")
    Set destWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set destWS = destWB.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    CopyData sourceWS.Range("H22"), destWS
    CopyData sourceWS.Range("D18"), destWS
    CopyData sourceWS.Range("G11"), destWS
    CopyData sourceWS.Range("B9"), destWS
    CopyData sourceWS.Range("J17"), destWS
    CopyData sourceWS.Range("A11"), destWS

End Sub

Sub CopyData(ByRef sourceCell As Range, ByRef destWS As Worksheet)
    '--- always adds the source data to the bottom of
    '    column A and fills in data in the same row
    '    to the right
    With destWS
        If IsEmpty(destWS.Range("A2")) Then
            destWS.Range("A2") = sourceCell
        Else
            '--- determine the last row with data, and then the
            '    last column of data on that row
            Dim lastRow As Long
            Dim lastCol As Long
            lastRow = .Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            lastCol = .Cells(lastRow, .Cells.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            
            '--- copies the value without formatting
            destWS.Cells(lastRow, lastCol + 1) = sourceCell
        End If
    End With
End Sub


Thank you PeterT.  This is a great educational addition to my adventure.

This was my new code. I used the one column that pasted the first data, then just used that row and indexed the column to paste the data.
Windows("JOB_COST_FORM.xlsm").Activate
Range("H22").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("MasterList_JOBCOST.xlsm").Activate         
Range("A2").Select
        If Range("A2") = "" Then
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Else: Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 2).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste
         Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
    Windows("JOB_COST_FORM.xlsm").Activate
Range("D18").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("MasterList_JOBCOST.xlsm").Activate
Range("A2").Select
        If Range("A2") = "" Then
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Else: Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 3).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste
         Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
ECT>>>

